# I May have a Virus. What Can I Do?

Tags: virus, virus-removal

So recently, I was Googling for images so that I can run Cisco router images on GNS3. I know I shouldn't be looking for images and I will now stop.

I came a across a site and I believe it gave me a virus. The virus was identified as Trojan/Bitrep.B virus. I inspected the issue and realized I had a suspicious download in my downloads directory. I had not clicked on anything to download, but the file was there.

I removed the virus, but I still get prompted from my antivirus (Windows Defender) that I have virus, and it downloads files such as "**Windows Loader 2.2.2-Daz**".

I have attempted to use Resource Monitor to determine if there is a process running or a process that is using the "Windows Loader..." file, but no luck. I am not to confident with Resource Monitor so I might missed something.

I am looking to run another Antivirus such AVG, to see if Windows missed anything. I am also looking to run Windows Network Monitor, to see where these files are coming from.

It is probably best that just backup my files, do fresh install of Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a fresh install would be a good idea. Just make sure that you don't backup the virus with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed and to be sure it's gone I would backup the user files and wipe the disk, then reinstall Windows.

If you have the time and not the skills to reinstall Windows then you could try a clean up.
There are several free anti malware programs. Start with [Spybot](https://www.safer-networking.org/mirrors26/) and [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com). Install them, update the definitions/signatures then run full scans.
Use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to delete temporary files, clean the Registry, uninstall unrequired software and check Windows Startup.

Maybe consider a second PC running Linux (or Raspberry Pi) to surf and download things that could contain viruses.